# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied when code is Executed

Tags: python

I was building a Rich Presence application and it worked totally fine until today. When I ran the code today it no longer worked and I get a error, mind you I didn't change a single bit of code. Does anyone know what could the problem be? I have attached the error. Also I ran the code as admin and it worked but it doesn't show the Rich Presence.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\MyName\Desktop\DiscoRP v2\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    from applet import quotegen
  File "c:\Users\MyName\Desktop\DiscoRP v2\applet\quotegen.py", line 11, in <module>
    connectionManager.connection(RPC)
  File "c:\Users\MyName\Desktop\DiscoRP v2\config\connectionManager.py", line 5, in connection
    RPC.connect()
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pypresence\presence.py", line 43, in connect
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.handshake())
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pypresence\baseclient.py", line 134, in handshake
    self.sock_writer, _ = await self.loop.create_pipe_connection(lambda: reader_protocol, self.ipc_path)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 333, in create_pipe_connection
    pipe = await f
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 652, in connect_pipe
    handle = _overlapped.ConnectPipe(address)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

What Am I supposed to do?

Comment: have you maybe previously run it with eleveted rights and now without?

Comment: Nope, I never ran it with Elevated Rights

Comment: Having the same problem. Code was running fine, now this error. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Because can't see your code, maybe you can check this [PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied](https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues/249)

Someone's solution looks like to  modify the path of the file.